Dismiss a .fullScreenCover() presentation that contains verticalScrollview, with a Down DragGesture
I am working on a SwiftUI app project that has a view, lets call it View1, that posses a button that will present a second view, lets call it View2, thanks to the instance method .fullScreenCover().
(Lets be honest, like 99% of today's App...)
Here is a simple version of my code that I recreated in order to simplify the debug process.
View that has to be presented with .fullScreenCover()(View2) :
struct VerticalScroll_view: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi luctus augue et arcu consectetur, in dignissim nunc maximus. Maecenas sit amet feugiat neque. Aliquam non enim diam. Aenean quis nisi quis nisl faucibus lacinia non eu libero. Phasellus vitae viverra erat, a rutrum nisi. Phasellus malesuada metus magna, id eleifend sem euismod nec. Mauris nec massa non diam pretium consequat et vitae odio. Curabitur pharetra placerat vestibulum. Cras sit amet cursus ligula, id imperdiet dui. Fusce viverra semper feugiat. Morbi mi est, varius ut nisi a, sodales pharetra nibh.\nVestibulum eleifend quis enim dignissim euismod. Ut sit amet tempus augue. Donec vitae sollicitudin est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque venenatis ante id felis faucibus malesuada. Vivamus sodales velit vel elit egestas, et cursus ipsum interdum. Vivamus vel maximus urna. Maecenas dictum condimentum diam a vehicula. Mauris efficitur orci velit, nec aliquam justo fringilla at. Cras pulvinar vestibulum elit id pellentesque. Nullam sapien dui, sodales sit amet fringilla at, elementum congue nibh. Phasellus iaculis massa nec rhoncus venenatis. Nam dignissim id nulla nec feugiat. Praesent iaculis fermentum pellentesque. Aliquam porttitor molestie dolor sit amet mattis.\nMaecenas sit amet orci vehicula, semper est ut, bibendum nibh. Nunc ullamcorper mi eu tellus maximus venenatis. Vivamus porta facilisis lectus, vitae pellentesque risus posuere quis. Integer at convallis lorem, eget condimentum justo. Duis efficitur ac ipsum at interdum. Morbi volutpat sollicitudin nulla efficitur eleifend. Donec auctor dapibus mi et mattis. Nullam congue arcu eu quam lacinia ultrices. Nunc id nibh nec velit vulputate vehicula sit amet vel erat. Donec lobortis leo nulla, ac cursus tellus vehicula vel. Sed iaculis dui eget sagittis malesuada. Donec auctor sit amet nibh molestie mattis. Cras ullamcorper est velit, posuere tincidunt dolor rutrum ut. Curabitur non quam vel erat vulputate venenatis eu eu diam. Sed et ipsum velit. Aliquam in efficitur mi.\nSuspendisse mattis, eros ac finibus bibendum, sem felis tristique ligula, sit amet dapibus dolor mi quis ipsum. Etiam gravida laoreet justo ut ultrices. Vestibulum ut luctus metus. Vestibulum gravida semper justo at pellentesque. Vivamus sit amet scelerisque magna. Ut suscipit bibendum velit, in eleifend dui ultrices non. Fusce eros ante, gravida sit amet condimentum eu, egestas ut tortor. Nam suscipit augue in nibh dictum, quis feugiat nunc feugiat. Integer a arcu hendrerit quam tempus maximus id nec mi. Quisque venenatis a nisi vel auctor. Phasellus vehicula ligula orci, quis consectetur lacus convallis sed. Morbi id justo sem. Aenean et quam ullamcorper, egestas magna sed, dignissim nulla. In in augue nec mi venenatis euismod.\nDonec eu arcu tincidunt, pellentesque velit sed, lobortis nulla. Donec ornare blandit tincidunt. Quisque accumsan ex sit amet iaculis egestas. Integer condimentum vehicula quam a aliquam. In faucibus non massa at molestie. Nulla scelerisque nibh ac urna feugiat venenatis. Donec nec elit dapibus, consequat neque placerat, elementum mi. Donec euismod odio urna, eget suscipit massa posuere id. Praesent malesuada felis nec gravida placerat.")
                    .padding()
            }
        }.background(.red.opacity(0.5))
    }
}

View that presents the view that contains the verticalScrollview (View1):
struct ViewtoDismiss: View {
    
    @State var presentVerticalScrollView: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Salut")
        Button(action: {presentVerticalScrollView.toggle()})
        {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentVerticalScrollView, content: {
            VerticalScroll_view()
                .presentationBackground(.clear)
                .offset(y: offset.height)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        if gesture.translation.height > 0 {
                            offset = gesture.translation
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        if offset.height > 250 {
                            withAnimation {
                                presentVerticalScrollView = false
                                offset = .zero
                            }
                        }else {
                            withAnimation {
                                offset = .zero
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
        })
    }
}

As you can see by using the given code, the downward drag gesture doesn't work correctly as it interact with the vertical scroll of the Scrollview.
What I'm trying to achieve:
I would like to have the same behavior as we can observe with the .sheet() method.
View1 with .sheet (View1):
struct ViewtoDismiss: View {
    
    @State var presentVerticalScrollView: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Salut")
        Button(action: {presentVerticalScrollView.toggle()})
        {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $presentVerticalScrollView, content: {
            VerticalScroll_view()
                .presentationBackground(.clear)
        })
    }
}

(As a context : I am not using the .sheetMethode, because I don't really like the little space at the top of the screen plus I'm having strange behavior with another method that should update background style.)
